# Purpose of /var/resource_config.json

Tags: magento

I'm trying to figure out what the purpose of the file /var/resource_config.json is in Magento.  It appears to perhaps be a caching of a configuration, but can't see where in the source code it is being created and/or updated.

I'm in the process of setting up local/dev/staging/prod environments for an EE1.12 build and want to figure out if I can safely exclude it from my repo or whether I need to script some updates to it for deploys.

Maybe the flash image uploader in admin creates it?

Any ideas or directions to look?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a configuration cache file for the "alternative media store" system.  This is a system where requests for media files are routed through `get.php`, and allows you to store media in the database instead of the file system.  (That may be a gross over simplification, as I've never used the feature myself)

You can safely, (**and should**) exclude this file from deployments/source control, as it's a cache file and will be auto generated as needed.  See the following codeblock in the root level `get.php` for more information.

```
if (!$mediaDirectory) {
    $config = Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage::getScriptConfig();
    $mediaDirectory = str_replace($bp . $ds, '', $config['media_directory']);
    $allowedResources = array_merge($allowedResources, $config['allowed_resources']);

    $relativeFilename = str_replace($mediaDirectory . '/', '', $pathInfo);

    $fp = fopen($configCacheFile, 'w');
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
        ftruncate($fp, 0);
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($config));
    }
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);

    checkResource($relativeFilename, $allowedResources);
}
```

Speaking in general terms, Magento's `var` folder serves the same purpose as [the *nix `var` folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

> Variable files—files whose content is expected to continually change during normal operation of the system—such as logs, spool files, and temporary e-mail files. Sometimes a separate partition

and should be isolated to particular systems (i.e. not a part of deployments)

Comment: Yes continuing on the same note it generally makes sense to exclude the entire /var folder from any deploy.

Comment: Are the xml files in /var/package cache files as well?

Comment: I would think including the .htaccess file in /var in version control would be prudent for security reasons

Comment: @Roscius Sort of.  They're files used by Magento Connect for package information.  Whether they go with a deployment depends entirely on your deployment strategy.