# Cannot add the item to shopping cart - Magento Safari Mac - Why?

Tags: magento

I am not sure why this is all of a sudden happening. I am getting an error only SOME browsers when attempting to add to cart. The error says "Cannot add the item to shopping cart."

It only happens on Safari and older browsers. I really could use some help. The following are in the error logs, if it helps:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/sitenamepublic_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1150

 PHP Warning:  ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/sitename/public_html/get.php on line 40

 PHP Warning:  ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/sitename/public_html/get.php on line 40

 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/sitename/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/carlton/template/catalog/product/test.phtml on line 68
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Comment: have you tried increasing the memory limit through the php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

You've got numerous errors there.

This one will halt PHP execution

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/sitenamepublic_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1150
```

as will this one

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/sitename/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/carlton/template/catalog/product/test.phtml on line 68
```

and the warning

```
PHP Warning:  ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/sitename/public_html/get.php on line 40
PHP Warning:  ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/sitename/public_html/get.php on line 40
```

are happening specifically for the `get.php` page.

Re: the `get.php` warnings, it sounds like you have the [alternative media storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522539/purpose-of-var-resource-config-json/10522950#10522950) feature turned on, and you uncommented the `ini_set` function call for `display_errors` in that file.  You web host doesn't allow you to do that on your production server, so re-comment that line

```
//File: get.php
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Re: `Call to a member function load()`, it seems like you have some custom code in

```
app/design/frontend/default/carlton/template/catalog/product/test.phtml
```

that's invalid.  As this isn't a part of the standard Magento distribution, you'll be unlikely to find a solution for this problem here.  Look in that file for calls to `load`, and figure out why the variable it's called on doesn't have an object in it.

Finally, Safari is most likely a red hearing.  The following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/sitenamepublic_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1150
```

Indicates PHP is running up against it's memory limits.  This will happen randomly depending on what page is requested, what state is loaded, etc.  `67108864` bytes is `64MB`.  Magento recommends your PHP memory limit be set to `256MB`, with `512MB` being far more common.  You'll need to get your web host to change the PHP `memory_limit` settings.  They won't want to do this.

All this points to your web host being unsuitable to run Magento.  I recommend [Nexcess](https://affiliate.nexcess.net/offer?item=MjQzODF8MTA) for starter Magento hosting needs (although I'm suspect, as a member of their affiliate program).  [Magento Speed Test](http://www.magespeedtest.com/) is a good place to see how various web-hosts handle Magento.

Comment: I am not sure where I can change the "#ini_set('display_errors', 1);" Can you direct me in the right direction, and thanks so much!